# Removing an unexplainable linebreak below a submit button?

Tags: html, css, button, doctype, line-breaks

while working on the layout of a simple site I'm doing, I came across a really annoying problem of which I just can't find the cause! I have no idea how to remove **the linebreak below my submit button**, extending the div which it's in downwards.

I've simplified [the page](http://67.23.226.97/~qgd/csswat.html) as much as I could, though there may still be some unnecessary elements in there.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
form {
    margin: 0
}
```

That's all you need.

---

Ok, I lied: That's all you need for Firefox/Chrome.

You have this:

```
<form action="something.php" 1 method="post">
                             ^ get rid of that 1
```

In IE, you need a modern doctype such as `<!DOCTYPE html>` to bring it out of Quirks mode.

You should add a doctype anyway.

Comment: Or use some sort of browser reset css if you're seeing this on a browser other than the one you're developing on :) But +1 to the answer above as the most terse!

Comment: Thank you, this is kind of a personal project thingie, so I don't care much for IE but it's nice you provided the information anyway :-]

Answer (score 2):

Your `form` element has a `margin-bottom` of `1em`, which is pushing its parent div downward by that amount.

Remove the margin and you should be OK.

Comment: And I thought it was the div's bottom padding! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Just add:

```
form {
   margin: 0;
}
```

You really ought to use a css reset, there are many good ones, such as the 2011 version of Eric Meyer's reset http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/.

This takes care of all the default unintended margins and paddings that sometimes vary from browser to browser.